# HTML table Export to Excel utf-8 characters error

Tags: angularjs, excel, export, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I have this below html (angular js based so it may have some angular tags)
https://gist.github.com/sudarshann/668ba8d3dda02da366f59af2bcc3187a

which I am trying to convert to xls export using the below code

```
var date = new Date();
var fileName = "Resumos " + tabName + " " + date + ".xls";
var fileRaw = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
fileRaw = fileRaw.split("↑").join("");
var file = fileRaw.split("↓").join("");

var blob = new Blob([file], {
   type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8;"
});
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

The result I am get in the Excel file (opened with MS Office 2016)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yyqowtzebaet7xl/error.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Relevant code is supposed to be in the question itself. we shouldn't have to click on multiple links just to review your problem. Questions should be self contained

Comment: @charlietfl the sample dataset seems bigger tough I just added one row. Thats I taught it wont be tooooooo long to read the question clearly.

Comment: *"relevant code"* not full data set or full application code. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for guidance on the posting. but I feel that the entire dataset I have is something like 1 mb . I have taken only the skeleton of the  of the dataset. Also I removed the link the code by just putting it over here.

Answer (score 0):

This code finally fixed my encoding issues.

```
        var date = new Date();
        var sheetName = "BASE DE CONCESSIONÁRIAS " + date;
        var fileName = sheetName + ".xls";
        var fileRaw = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        fileRaw = fileRaw.split("↑").join("");
        var file = fileRaw.split("↓").join("");
        $log.info("here ", file);

          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>{table}</body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

            var toExcel = file;
            var ctx = {
                worksheet: sheetName || '',
                table: toExcel
            };

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = fileName;
            link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            link.click();
```

PS: I am still not sure why this fixed the issue or how this is different. It will be nice if some one can explain me on how and why this works and not the code in the question